# Dockerize existing Laravel 8 project with dependencies - how to run composer update inside docker?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have install Docker on a clean install of Monterey. I can create a new Laravel 9 project.  I also managed to install a container for mySQL and one for phpMyAdmin which I can access in the browser.

After updating the Dockerfile as advised (see below) when I try to dockerize an existing Laravel 8 project (after creating the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files as explained in [this article](https://dev.to/pierangelo1982/dockerize-an-existing-laravel-application-with-docker-compose-3l5m)) with extra depencies, I get the following errors:

```
$ docker-compose build
db uses an image, skipping
phpmyadmin uses an image, skipping
Building app
[+] Building 56.5s (8/11)                                                                                                                       
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 649B                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.0                                                                                 5.0s
 => [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/php:8.0@sha256:28d552fb96c848fcaa8b9fba9fedcaccbfadf7a108dc896be7cbc78b11417673                          13.5s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/php:8.0@sha256:28d552fb96c848fcaa8b9fba9fedcaccbfadf7a108dc896be7cbc78b11417673                           0.0s
 ...
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                         12.6s
 => => transferring context: 289.97MB                                                                                                     12.5s
 => [2/7] RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git                                                               17.9s
 => [3/7] RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer                         6.6s
 => ERROR [4/7] RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip                                                                              13.5s 
------                                                                                                                                          
 > [4/7] RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip:                                                                                          
#7 1.864 Configuring for:                                                                                                                       
#7 1.864 PHP Api Version:         20200930                                                                                                      
#7 1.864 Zend Module Api No:      20200930                                                                                                      
#7 1.864 Zend Extension Api No:   420200930                                                                                                     
#7 2.692 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
#7 2.694 checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
#7 2.696 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
#7 2.732 checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
#7 2.732 checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
#7 2.743 checking for cc... cc
#7 2.774 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
#7 2.887 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
#7 2.889 checking for suffix of executables... 
#7 2.928 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
#7 2.996 checking for suffix of object files... o
#7 3.018 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
#7 3.042 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
#7 3.065 checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
#7 3.112 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
#7 3.177 checking for icc... no
#7 3.188 checking for suncc... no
#7 3.199 checking for system library directory... lib
#7 3.199 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
#7 3.244 checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#7 3.252 checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#7 3.252 checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#7 3.298 checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
#7 3.298 checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
#7 3.299 checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930
#7 3.300 checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
#7 3.300 checking if debug is enabled... no
#7 3.330 checking if zts is enabled... no
#7 3.347 checking for gawk... no
#7 3.348 checking for nawk... nawk
#7 3.349 checking if nawk is broken... no
#7 3.352 checking whether to enable PDO support... yes, shared
#7 3.374 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
#7 3.378 checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
#7 3.384 checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
#7 3.387 checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
#7 3.388 checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
#7 3.392 checking whether ln -s works... yes
#7 3.392 checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
#7 3.417 checking for ANSI C header files... yes
#7 3.533 checking for sys/types.h... yes
#7 3.566 checking for sys/stat.h... yes
#7 3.603 checking for stdlib.h... yes
#7 3.635 checking for string.h... yes
#7 3.671 checking for memory.h... yes
#7 3.714 checking for strings.h... yes
#7 3.747 checking for inttypes.h... yes
#7 3.787 checking for stdint.h... yes
#7 3.821 checking for unistd.h... yes
#7 3.861 checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
#7 3.892 checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
#7 3.904 checking for dlfcn.h... yes
#7 3.906 checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
#7 3.912 checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
#7 3.984 checking for objdir... .libs
#7 3.988 checking for ar... ar
#7 3.989 checking for ranlib... ranlib
#7 3.990 checking for strip... strip
#7 4.046 checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
#7 4.073 checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
#7 4.074 checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
#7 4.098 checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
#7 4.217 checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
#7 4.251 checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
#7 4.268 checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
#7 4.297 checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
#7 4.315 checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
#7 4.315 checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
#7 4.320 checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
#7 4.320 checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
#7 4.320 checking whether to build static libraries... no
#7 4.505 
#7 4.505 creating libtool
#7 4.528 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
#7 4.609 configure: patching config.h.in
#7 4.612 configure: creating ./config.status
#7 4.676 config.status: creating config.h
#7 4.729 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/pdo/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c /usr/src/php/ext/pdo/pdo.c -o pdo.lo 
#7 4.833 mkdir .libs
...
#7 7.480 creating pdo.la
#7 7.489 (cd .libs && rm -f pdo.la && ln -s ../pdo.la pdo.la)
#7 7.492 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/pdo/libtool --mode=install cp ./pdo.la /usr/src/php/ext/pdo/modules
#7 7.528 cp ./.libs/pdo.so /usr/src/php/ext/pdo/modules/pdo.so
#7 7.532 cp ./.libs/pdo.lai /usr/src/php/ext/pdo/modules/pdo.la
#7 7.553 PATH="$PATH:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/src/php/ext/pdo/modules
#7 7.556 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#7 7.557 Libraries have been installed in:
#7 7.557    /usr/src/php/ext/pdo/modules
#7 7.557 
#7 7.557 If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
#7 7.557 in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
#7 7.557 specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
#7 7.557 flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
#7 7.557    - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
#7 7.557      during execution
#7 7.557    - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
#7 7.557      during linking
#7 7.557    - use the `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
#7 7.557    - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'
#7 7.557 
#7 7.557 See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
#7 7.557 more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
#7 7.559 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#7 7.561 
#7 7.562 Build complete.
#7 7.564 Don't forget to run 'make test'.
#7 7.565 
#7 7.569 + strip --strip-all modules/pdo.so
#7 7.598 Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/
#7 7.741 Installing header files:          /usr/local/include/php/
#7 7.836 Installing PDO headers:           /usr/local/include/php/ext/pdo/
#7 8.006 
#7 8.006 warning: pdo (pdo.so) is already loaded!
#7 8.006 
#7 8.008 find . -name \*.gcno -o -name \*.gcda | xargs rm -f
#7 8.013 find . -name \*.lo -o -name \*.o | xargs rm -f
#7 8.018 find . -name \*.la -o -name \*.a | xargs rm -f
#7 8.022 find . -name \*.so | xargs rm -f
#7 8.027 find . -name .libs -a -type d|xargs rm -rf
#7 8.031 rm -f libphp.la      modules/* libs/*
#7 8.033 rm -f ext/opcache/jit/zend_jit_x86.c
#7 8.064 Configuring for:
#7 8.064 PHP Api Version:         20200930
#7 8.064 Zend Module Api No:      20200930
#7 8.064 Zend Extension Api No:   420200930
#7 8.831 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
#7 8.834 checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
#7 8.836 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
#7 8.870 checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
#7 8.870 checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
#7 8.873 checking for cc... cc
#7 8.904 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
#7 8.946 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
#7 8.947 checking for suffix of executables... 
#7 8.988 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
#7 9.031 checking for suffix of object files... o
#7 9.053 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
#7 9.075 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
#7 9.097 checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
#7 9.130 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
#7 9.182 checking for icc... no
#7 9.193 checking for suncc... no
#7 9.204 checking for system library directory... lib
#7 9.204 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
#7 9.248 checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#7 9.254 checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#7 9.255 checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#7 9.298 checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
#7 9.299 checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
#7 9.299 checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930
#7 9.299 checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
#7 9.299 checking if debug is enabled... no
#7 9.316 checking if zts is enabled... no
#7 9.332 checking for gawk... no
#7 9.333 checking for nawk... nawk
#7 9.334 checking if nawk is broken... no
#7 9.336 checking for MySQL support for PDO... yes, shared
#7 9.336 checking for the location of libz... no
#7 9.338 checking for MySQL UNIX socket location... 
#7 9.339 checking for PDO includes... /usr/local/include/php/ext
#7 9.348 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
#7 9.352 checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
#7 9.358 checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
#7 9.362 checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
#7 9.362 checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
#7 9.365 checking whether ln -s works... yes
#7 9.365 checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
#7 9.383 checking for ANSI C header files... yes
#7 9.492 checking for sys/types.h... yes
#7 9.526 checking for sys/stat.h... yes
#7 9.558 checking for stdlib.h... yes
#7 9.590 checking for string.h... yes
#7 9.625 checking for memory.h... yes
#7 9.658 checking for strings.h... yes
#7 9.692 checking for inttypes.h... yes
#7 9.728 checking for stdint.h... yes
#7 9.762 checking for unistd.h... yes
#7 9.799 checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
#7 9.831 checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
#7 9.846 checking for dlfcn.h... yes
#7 9.848 checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
#7 9.855 checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
#7 9.931 checking for objdir... .libs
#7 9.935 checking for ar... ar
#7 9.936 checking for ranlib... ranlib
#7 9.936 checking for strip... strip
#7 9.994 checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
#7 10.02 checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
#7 10.02 checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
#7 10.04 checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
#7 10.12 checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
#7 10.15 checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
#7 10.17 checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
#7 10.19 checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
#7 10.21 checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
#7 10.21 checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
#7 10.22 checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
#7 10.22 checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
#7 10.22 checking whether to build static libraries... no
#7 10.40 
#7 10.40 creating libtool
#7 10.42 appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
#7 10.50 configure: patching config.h.in
#7 10.50 configure: creating ./config.status
#7 10.56 config.status: creating config.h
#7 10.61 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/include -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/main -I/usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -c /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/pdo_mysql.c -o pdo_mysql.lo 
#7 10.72 mkdir .libs
...
#7 11.74 creating pdo_mysql.la
#7 11.75 (cd .libs && rm -f pdo_mysql.la && ln -s ../pdo_mysql.la pdo_mysql.la)
#7 11.76 /bin/bash /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/libtool --mode=install cp ./pdo_mysql.la /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/modules
#7 11.79 cp ./.libs/pdo_mysql.so /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/modules/pdo_mysql.so
#7 11.79 cp ./.libs/pdo_mysql.lai /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/modules/pdo_mysql.la
#7 11.82 PATH="$PATH:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/modules
#7 11.82 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#7 11.82 Libraries have been installed in:
#7 11.82    /usr/src/php/ext/pdo_mysql/modules
#7 11.82 
#7 11.82 If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
#7 11.82 in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
#7 11.82 specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
#7 11.82 flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
#7 11.82    - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
#7 11.82      during execution
#7 11.82    - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
#7 11.82      during linking
#7 11.82    - use the `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
#7 11.82    - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'
#7 11.82 
#7 11.82 See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
#7 11.82 more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
#7 11.82 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#7 11.82 
#7 11.82 Build complete.
#7 11.83 Don't forget to run 'make test'.
#7 11.83 
#7 11.83 + strip --strip-all modules/pdo_mysql.so
#7 11.86 Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/
#7 11.93 find . -name \*.gcno -o -name \*.gcda | xargs rm -f
#7 11.93 find . -name \*.lo -o -name \*.o | xargs rm -f
#7 11.94 find . -name \*.la -o -name \*.a | xargs rm -f
#7 11.94 find . -name \*.so | xargs rm -f
#7 11.95 find . -name .libs -a -type d|xargs rm -rf
#7 11.95 rm -f libphp.la      modules/* libs/*
#7 11.96 rm -f ext/opcache/jit/zend_jit_x86.c
#7 11.99 Configuring for:
#7 11.99 PHP Api Version:         20200930
#7 11.99 Zend Module Api No:      20200930
#7 11.99 Zend Extension Api No:   420200930
#7 12.78 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
#7 12.78 checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
#7 12.78 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
#7 12.81 checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
#7 12.81 checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
#7 12.82 checking for cc... cc
#7 12.84 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
#7 12.88 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
#7 12.88 checking for suffix of executables... 
#7 12.92 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
#7 12.96 checking for suffix of object files... o
#7 12.99 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
#7 13.01 checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
#7 13.03 checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
#7 13.06 checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
#7 13.12 checking for icc... no
#7 13.13 checking for suncc... no
#7 13.14 checking for system library directory... lib
#7 13.14 checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
#7 13.18 checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#7 13.19 checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#7 13.19 checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#7 13.23 checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
#7 13.23 checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
#7 13.23 checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930
#7 13.23 checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
#7 13.23 checking if debug is enabled... no
#7 13.24 checking if zts is enabled... no
#7 13.26 checking for gawk... no
#7 13.26 checking for nawk... nawk
#7 13.26 checking if nawk is broken... no
#7 13.26 checking for zip archive read/write support... yes, shared
#7 13.27 checking for libzip >= 0.11 libzip != 1.3.1 libzip != 1.7.0... no
#7 13.28 configure: error: Package requirements (libzip >= 0.11 libzip != 1.3.1 libzip != 1.7.0) were not met:
#7 13.28 
#7 13.28 No package 'libzip' found
#7 13.28 No package 'libzip' found
#7 13.28 No package 'libzip' found
#7 13.28 
#7 13.28 Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
#7 13.28 installed software in a non-standard prefix.
#7 13.28 
#7 13.28 Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBZIP_CFLAGS
#7 13.28 and LIBZIP_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
#7 13.28 See the pkg-config man page for more details.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
```

composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.4|^8.0",
    "alexusmai/laravel-file-manager": "^2.5",
    "ecrmnn/lorem": "^1.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "intervention/image": "^2.6",
    "joshtronic/php-loremipsum": "^1.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.2",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "platform-check": false
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

running docker-compose build

Comment: can you share composer.json?

Comment: You have a dependency issues in composer... it is not a Docker issue... `alexusmai/laravel-file-manager v2.5.4 requires ext-zip *`: means you don't have `php-zip` or `zip` installed (I cannot remember if `php-zip` exists). And you have `nette/schema v1.2.1 requires php >=7.1 <8.1 -> your php version (8.1.3)` meaning it does **NOT** support `PHP >= 8.1` and you have `8.1.3`.... to solve this last one, you may be able to do `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`...

Comment: Thank you @matiaslauriti. How do I install php-zip or zip in Docker container? And how do I update all dependencies in Docker?  Can I do a global update or should I update one by one?

Comment: The comment at the end says to type php --ini but zsh says command not found. Why?  Same when I type composer update.  Php and composer must be there... How do I access them?

Comment: I would need to see your `Dockerfile`, but you should have something like `RUN docker-php-ext-install xxx yyy zzz` and you just need to add `RUN docker-php-ext-install xxx yyy zzz zip`

Comment: Thank you @matiaslauriti.  I really need to get this working.  I have added the Dockerfile.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? `docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql` looks like you already know how install other extensions

Comment: @PaulGodard I have told you how to solve the issue...

Comment: @matiaslauriti sorry I had to attend an urgent family matter.  I will carry on today.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Sorry for the delay.  I have updated Dockerfile : php 8.0 & added zip but I still get errors I am not sure to understand... is it the zip creating the problem at the end?

Comment: "No package 'libzip' found" - to install the ZIP extension, you need to install `libzip-dev` using `apt-get` first.

Comment: @NicoHaase But there is already a line for RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git.  So should I simply add libzip-dev at the end?

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? Usually, a package or library **without** the `-dev` suffix does not contain enough data to compile new stuff, but solely those data needed to run its operations

Comment: @NicoHaase That helped but now there are other errors...

Comment: ....then you should probably go on and install whatever is missing. As all extensions take the same approach, it should not be too hard to guess how to resolve the new problem

Comment: I did that for exif already but now it seems that it is a db issue...
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: SELECT * FROM pages WHERE (menu = 'seo') LIMIT 1)

Comment: @NicoHaase Can we continue in chat?

Answer (score 2):

> alexusmai/laravel-file-manager v2.5.4 requires ext-zip

This means that you need to install the zip extension [1].

> nette/schema v1.2.1 requires php >=7.1 <8.1 -> your php version (8.1.3)

This means your packages are not compatible with php version 8.1. You are installing php 8.1.3 because you use `FROM php:8` which takes the latest version.

So change your Dockerfile to something like

```
FROM php:8.0
# ...
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip
# ...
```

- [1] [supported docker-php-extensions](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer#supported-php-extensions)